# LINQ and ReSharper

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

Hi I have the following code:

```
if (!_jobs.Any(j => j.Id == emailJob.Id))
{
}
```

This code should find any elements which satisfy the condition. So I would assume that it should return after finding the first element, something like this:

```
if (!_jobs.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == emailJob.Id) != null)
{
}
```

Resharper tries to simplify this LINQ expression to:

```
if (_jobs.All(j => j.Id != emailJob.Id))
{
}
```

This seems less efficient to me because it has to check that every single element satisifies the inverse condition.

Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding how LINQ works.

Joe

Comment: you would have to check the whole list if all of them were different than that Id anyway. Even in the first example.

Comment: How can you tell that person X does not have any red socks when there is still a sock in the drawer that you haven't looked at yet?

Comment: Yes but if your in a situation where the list is likely to contain an element with a matching ID then its faster. Assuming that I've understood how .Any() works correctly.

Comment: It's as efficient - `!Any()` has to check all of them too, because the last element could still satisfy the condition. It just comes down to Boolean algebra - NOT OR is equivalent to AND NOT.

Comment: No, both of them will stop as soon as they fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Any` and `All` will stop looking immediately upon the condition failing.

If you are looking for more than just taking our word or anecdotal evidence, you can see from the source that this is what it is doing.

[image: Decompiled Any and All methods]

There is an extra inversion in the `All` method after the predicate is applied. This is a relative 0 performance impact, so code readability is the main concern.

Comment: I see - I should have really realised that, not sure what's wrong with me today. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The two versions are mirror approaches and do exactly the same amount of work.

When you say "if *none* of the items satisfy this condition" (`!Any`), then *all* of the items have to be checked in order to get a definite answer.

ReSharper's suggestion is useful because it guides you towards using the method that more clearly shows what is going to happen: `All` jobs will have to be examined.

Comment: I think the most important note here is that the suggestion is not for efficiency, but readability.

Comment: But in this case it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any job that does match the emailJob id, then the `.Any()` approach can abort early.  By the same token,  the `.All()` approach can stop working as soon as it finds a condition that's false, which will happen at the same job.  The efficiency should be about the same.